# Binary search approach not working for all cases

Tags: python, binary-search

I'm trying to do a LeetCode question:

> Given an array of integers nums which is sorted in ascending order, and an integer target, write a function to search target in nums. If target exists, then return its index. Otherwise, return -1.
>
> You must write an algorithm with O(log n) runtime complexity.

I have attempted to approach the problem using recursion by utilizing the offset difference between the middle indices of each subarray. However, in each instance, there is another case where the code fails. Any thoughts ?

```
def binary(nums, target, answer):
    n = len(nums)  

    if len(nums) == 1 and nums[0] != target: 
        #special case where the subarray is length one and it doesnt match the target
        return -1 

    if nums[n // 2] == target:
        return answer
    elif nums[n // 2] > target:
        answer = binary(nums[:n // 2], target, answer)
    else:
        answer = binary(nums[n // 2 + 1:], target, answer+(n // 2) + 1)

    return answer

class Solution(object):
    def search(self, nums, target):
        #Adjusting the offset in the beginning
        if nums[0] == target:
            return 0
        elif nums[len(nums) // 2] >= target:
            return binary(nums, target, len(nums) // 2)
        else:
            return binary(nums, target, 0)
```

Comment: In general, this is not the best approach when you are aiming for efficiency. Each time you do something like `nums[n // 2 + 1:]` you need to create a new list which makes it hard to remain at O(log n). A more traditional approach is to track a low and high index.

Comment: I don't understand what the `answer` argument is for. Why do you return `answer` when the index is `n//2`?

Comment: @Barmar I think this is an attempt to keep track of the correct index even through they are passing a new array into the function (and hence losing the context of the original array indices).

Comment: Makes sense.  A better name would be something like `offset`.

Comment: @Mark oh yeah it completely diminishes the O(log n ) argument. Sorry just switched over to Python and takes me some time to realize the complexity of the in-built functions. Thanks. I'll go with the traditional binary search approach then

Comment: The whole point of a binary search is that it should run in O(log(n)) time.  But you're copying half of the least at each step.  That immediately pushes the time complexity to at least O(n), and possible something like O(n*log(n)).  Even if you get it to give the right answer, and it's "accepted", you failed the task.  It's not binary search if you're doing list copying.  In fact, it's strictly *worse* than doing a linear search.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for recursion. The trick is to maintain a lower bound and an upper bound (`+ 1`) on the remaining range in which the `target` value may still be. In each iteration, look at the “middle” (*median*, sort of, albeit not by the statistical meaning) of the range. If its value is above the `target`, make it the `upper` bound. If it is below the target, make it the `lower` bound (`+ 1`). The last remaining possibility is that you’ve found the `target`. If the [`lower`, `upper`) interval collapses, then the `target` was not found.

The only surprising bit may be `lower = current + 1` versus `upper = current`, but given that `upper` has the “one past end” meaning (in the same sense as in e.g. `range(lower, upper)`), this shouldn’t be surprising after all.

```py
def search(nums, target):
  lower, upper = 0, len(nums)
  while lower < upper:
    current = (lower + upper) // 2
    if nums[current] < target:
      lower = current + 1
    elif nums[current] > target:
      upper = current
    else:
      return current
  return -1
```

A more interesting task would be to not just find *any* occurrence of `target`, but to also figure out the entire index range of `nums` equal to `target` — still in logarithmic time.  (A possible approach would be to search for an element equal to `target` such that the following element is larger than `target` (or the last element if equal to `target`), then search for an element equal to `target` such that the previous element is smaller than `target` (or the first element if equal to `target`), then summarize the result.)